# PHPTAL Conditional Attribute

Tags: html, template-tal, phptal

Given a metal macro that looks like this:

```
<tal:block metal:define-macro="foo">
    <option value="1">Foo</option>
    <option value="2">Bar</option>
    <option value="3">Baz</option>
</tal:block>
```

And a template which uses the macro like this:

```
<select>
    <tal:block tal:define="selectedValue 2" metal:use-macro="foo" />
</select>
```

**What do I need to add to the macro, such that the resulting HTML looks like this:**

```
<select>
    <option value="1">Foo</option>
    <option value="2" selected="selected">Bar</option>
    <option value="3">Baz</option>
</select>
```

I've tried various different methods using the `php:` expression and even defining my own TALES function, but nothing seems to give me what I'm looking for.

Browsers treat any option where the `selected` attribute appears as actually selected.  That means that `selected`, `selected=""`, `selected="foo"`, etc. will all make the option selected.  PHPTAL has a built in `attribute value | nothing` syntax that resolves this, but this only falls back to `nothing` in the case that `value` is empty, which doesn't help me, since I need to compare it to a value.  Something like this (doesn't work):

```
<option value="2" tal:attributes="selected (selectedValue == 2 ? 'selected' : NULL) | nothing">Bar</option>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should suffice:

```
tal:attributes="selected php:selectedValue == 2"
```

PHPTAL knows about attributes like `selected` and `checked` and will convert boolean to correct value.

`php:selectedValue == 2 ? 'selected' : NULL` would work as well.

Comment: What if I have to compare "selectedValue" with repeat/item/key in the loop (eg, options in select tag).

Comment: @Meglio use `repeat.item.key` in `php:`

Comment: I'd like to know how to do this without resorting to php: